# Representation of Lookup table

Tags: entity-relationship, lookup-tables

How can I represent my lookup tables in technical reports?

In other words, the ER model is used to represent a database, 
but what about lookup tables?

Answer (score 3):

To recover a conceptual model (entity sets, attributes and relationships) from a physical model (tables and columns), we first have to understand the logical model. This means understanding the domains and functional dependencies which are represented by the lookup table.

*Lookup table* is a common term which can mean different things. I generally understand it as a table which represents a domain with a surrogate key, and associates it with a name and/or a few other attributes. In the ER model, these would be simple entity relations, and leaves / terminal nodes in the graph of entity sets.

If a lookup table records facts about only one type of thing (represented by the key of the lookup table), then you can represent that type as an entity set (rectangle) with an attribute (oval) for each dependent column, and draw relationships (diamonds) to connect it to other entity sets as required. Look for foreign key columns / constraints in other tables to find these relationships.

For example, consider the following physical model:

[image: Car Sales physical model]

`CarMake` and `CarModel` are examples of lookup tables. This isn't a very good model, since in the real world `CarModelId` determines `CarMakeId`, while the model treats them as independent elements in `CarSales`. However, since the point of the example is to focus on lookup tables, I'll use it as is.

In this case, `CarMake` and `CarModel` describe a single entity set each. Their functional dependencies are `CarMakeId -> CarMakeName` and `CarModelId -> CarModelName`. In `CarSales`, we've got `CarSaleId -> RegNumber, Price, SoldOn` (attributes) and `CarSaleId -> CarMakeId, CarModelId` (relationships).

In this case our ER model is similar to the physical model:

[image: Car sales conceptual model]

However, in some cases, you may find multiple types of things combined into one lookup table due to the similar physical structure. This doesn't affect the logical or conceptual models, but makes it more complicated to recover since we have to understand how the table is used to unpack it.

Comment: thank you Mr.reagan
 but let me explain my goal, i have alphabet learning system 
contains :
1-  learn mode (contains learning numbers and letters )
2- exam mode ( ask questions)

actually, i have an Accesse file hold those  numbers, letters, questions
i do not really know how this will be represented. there is no relation (dimond) connects these two modes.

my figure will be 2 rectangulars with attributes, but wher is the relation.
can you help please .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand your model based on your description. Please edit your question to show the physical table structures.

Comment: I mean there is no relations between entities, each entity has atributes but no realtion connect them, how can i represent them ? as stand-alone tabels with no lines indecate the relations ?

Comment: Your terminology is confused. I believe you're talking about relationships (as in the entity-relationship model) rather than relations. In table diagrams, lines between tables don't represent relationships, they represent FK constraints. Relationships are represented by two or more entity columns in the same table. Anyway, I still don't understand your model; an example would really help me to help you.